# erro src iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

o meu código:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" *ngFor="let g of gag">
    <div *ngIf="g.tipo == 2">
      <iframe width="280" height="162" [src]="g.caminho" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

e o erro apresentado no console:

```
ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)
at DomSanitizerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize (platform-browser.js:1812)
at setElementProperty (core.js:8260)
at checkAndUpdateElementValue (core.js:8212)
at checkAndUpdateElementInline (core.js:8159)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10503)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:11102)
at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:11088)
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (GaleriaComponent.html:24)
```

Alguem sabe me dizer como posso solucionar o erro?

Comment: No log já esta te informando aonde buscar informações: http://g.co/ng/security#xss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está no `[src]="g.caminho"`, não deves passar caminhos dessa forma.

Mais informação: https://angular.io/guide/security#xss